# Re-sizing image differs on various images?

Tags: php, mysql, image

I am having an issue with displaying images the same size as a rectangle. 
I have the below code which displays the default image (if file isn't uploaded) as a nice rectangle which looks good, however if I upload images that are Portrait or landscape it totally messes up the image size and the website is all over the shop? Here is the original code :

```
<?php


$sql = "SELECT * FROM pages ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3";

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql)or die(mysqli_error());

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $page_name = $row['page_name'];
    $page_dp = $row['page_dp'];


?>

  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="pageimg/<? echo $page_dp; ?>" alt="Page Image">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3><? echo $page_name; ?></h3>
        <div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="10" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 10%">10%
    <span class="sr-only">10% Complete (success)</span>
  </div>
</div>
        <p><b>£100.00</b> Target | <b>£10.00</b> Raised</p>
        Here is a little info about this current topic, please help us raise more than we can! We need your help!
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-success" role="button">Donate Now</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Details</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



<?
} 


mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>
```

I've tried this:

```
<img src="pageimg/<? echo $page_dp; ?>" alt="Page Image" width="618" height="413">
```

And tried adding height and width styles to the CSS codes but nothing seems to work? Any ideas? Here is an example of the webpage to show what I mean...

```
http://fundfeeder.co.uk/pages.php
```

The top section is where I am trying to edit but the bottom section is how it should be lined up perfectly?

Comment: You could use background images and style these with css: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30184906/resizing-cropping-image-to-adjust-into-layout/30185112#30185112

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achiev? Should all images look the same width / height as the default images? Or do you want all images to have width / height 618/413?

Comment: I mean, with a bit of simple CSS I can easily resize those images to the same width/height as your default images. The images look rather distorded because of the forced resize, but it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Avoid JS errors with linking jQuery >= 1.9.1
Edit: I see there is 1.11.2, but console shouts this message: `Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher`

Comment: Edit2: seems `bootstrap.js` expects different name of jquery file to be able to parse it and conclude which version it is. Contrary to that, you have version set as directory name, not as file name. Solve that first.

Comment: @icecub Yeah I am trying to have any image uploaded look exactly the same size as the default images, what CSS would I use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
<img src="pageimg/<? echo $page_dp; ?>" alt="Page Image">
```

With:

```
<img src="pageimg/<? echo $page_dp; ?>" class="pageImage" alt="Page Image">
```

And add the following to your CSS files:

```
.pageImage {
    width: 348px;
    height: 233px;
}
```

Or if you prefer doing it inline:

```
<img src="pageimg/<? echo $page_dp; ?>" style="width:348px;height:233px;" alt="Page Image">
```

Comment: Perfect, done the trick! So why is it when I added the height and width within the img tag did it not change anything?

Comment: @Aidanpt6 Without reviewing your code, that might be hard to say. Could be your doctype declaration set to html 5, in which case you're not supposed to do any "designing" with html 4 attributes.